# Unable to retrieve value of textbox with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This should really be easy and it has worked on every page of my site except for this one.  I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#center, #west").css("min-height","110%");
    $("#positionName").NobleCount('#positionNameCounter', {max_chars: 50, on_negative: 'go_red', on_positive: 'go_green' });
    $("#cName").NobleCount('#cName_counter',{ max_chars: 255, on_negative: 'go_red', on_positive: 'go_green' });
    $("#cURL").NobleCount('#cURL_counter',{ max_chars: 255, on_negative: 'go_red', on_positive: 'go_green' });
    $(".info th").addClass("ui-widget-header").css("border","none").attr("style","font-size:14px; padding:7px;");
    $(".info").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    $(".info td").addClass("padding");
    $(".bold").addClass("ui-tabs-nav");
    var company = $("#company").val();
    $("#checkAvailability").click(function(){
        alert(company);
    });
});
</script>
```

And here is my html:

```
<input type="text" name="company" id="company" maxlength="40" title="Desired Company Name" style="width:50%;" /><span style="width:20%; padding-left:5px; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline;" id="checkAvailability">
```

Its killing me b/c I can't figure it out for the life of me.  Thanks in advance,

Jeff

Edit: Andy E. hit it on the nail, thanks for you help.

Comment: use firebug and see if there are any js errors in you're code .

Comment: Andy E. got it poelinca, I was trying to get the value without it being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text box doesn't have a default value, so it will be blank when the `company` variable is set using the following line in your ready handler:

```
var company = $("#company").val(); // Empty here since no value has been set
```

Change it to:

```
var company = $("#company");
$("#checkAvailability").click(function(){
    alert(company.val());
});
```